# Kafka - mirror from one server to another server

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm trying to mirror Kafka real-time data from one server to another server.

Found a tool called 'Mirror Maker' at Apache website.

[Apache Kafka Mirror Maker][1]
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330#Kafkamirroring(MirrorMaker)-Howtosetupamirror

But the description is too simple, without configuration detail of consumer.config & producer.config files.

How to deploy this tool with correct config files for mirroring data between two Kafka servers for:

1. Real-time topics transfer
2. fault-tolerant under unstable network

Any other possible way to achieve this is also very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read this: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation#basic_ops_mirror_maker

Comment: There is also: http://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/deployment.html#mirroring-data-between-clusters

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Yes, I've read those. But there aren't much differences compared to the URL I provide above? The URL you provided call the mirror tool inside shell script, and mine call it directly.

And my real point is 2. fault-tolerant under unstable network. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Apache's Mirror Maker is a relatively simple tool, this is why all the documentation you read doesn't seem incredible informative. There isn't much information to give. All it does is consume data from cluster A and produce to cluster B. Mirror Maker does provide real-time topic transfer but as far as stability goes you may need to look to third party tools such as https://eng.uber.com/ureplicator/.

Comment: Did you mean, _Consume_ it from Cluster A and _Produce_ it to Cluster B, instead?